# No response in postback after writing binary to the response

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download, response

**Requirement:**
I want to download a file (*.docx) on the click of a button, first I read the bytes of the file, then I write the bytes to the response, this works fine and I have used this code several times before, but I am getting this weird behavior where the code executes successfully, without exceptions, but there is no response being sent back to the client (nothing happens, no response, no file download), furthermore, if I put the code in Page_Load event, the code works flawlessly, it only does not work in the button click event(i.e. on postbacks), here is the code that I am using:

```
Dim arrBytes() = File.ReadAllBytes(strFilePath)
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.docx")
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", arrBytes.Length.ToString())
Response.BinaryWrite(arrBytes)
Response.Flush()
Response.SuppressContent = True
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I tried `'Response.WriteFile` instead of`Response.BinaryWrite` and `Response.End` instead of `ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` but nothing succeeded.

Comment: Did you call Response.Close()?

Comment: @OldProgrammer The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Response.Close()`. Seems to me it's not meant to be directly used.

Comment: @OldProgrammer No, I never called `Response.Close`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an UpdatePanel in the MasterPage, the problem was solved when I registered the button as a post back control ... That hurts I know.

So I solved it by using this line of code in the `Page_Load` event:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterPostBackControl(btnSubmit)
```